# Does the our karma influence the gender of the child that we might have? Does the gender indicate something about our karma?

Tags: vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

Let me try to convey my question better.

Keeping the gender-based Hindu stereotypes aside, usually, in normal Hindu tradition, after marriage, it is the girl who moves to the boy's side and lives with him.
During the marriage, a lot of expenditure, the marriage expenses are borne by the father of the girl and they are not as privileged as the boy's family.

Recently, I noticed a couple of elder people conversing that those who have girl children alone and no male child are considered sinners. I am not sure why they said this. But I heard them saying that the parents of the girl child are sinners. Maybe, is it because, their final rites cannot be done by a girl/female (as it requires only a male child to do?? Or is it for a different reason? This is clearly a gender bias, right?

If someone knows the reason for the above, please let me know.

Contemplating the above conversation, bought me to a bigger question.

Does our past karma determine whether we will get a girl or a male child?
Implying, if we have a lot of bad karma, we might get a girl child. Implying that we need to suffer to protect her more than a boy, spend for her more than a boy and finally, give her to a boy who moves with him for the rest of her life. And finally, we might not have anyone to do final rites.

Does our previous karma have any influence on the gender of our children?

Please let me know.

Comment: You need to provide a real reference, not "I overheard"

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, yes, I understand. I am not able to find the exact reference. But I have only heard the sayings and practices by word of mouth. In that case, could you please let me know your thoughts on this topic?

Comment: There is nothing good or bad karma in having a girl child, no need to mix the misogynistic elements in the culture with traditional doctrine of karma. I don't know any text which says that having girl child is pāpa or a result of it.